# How can I get the same result of the "tr///" operator from perl in java

Tags: java, perl

What is the fastest way to implement the perl operator `tr///`?

For instance, if I were to have a String `"ATGCATGC"` and I use perl `tr/GTCA/CAGT/` then I would get `"TACGTACG"`.

Is there a single java function that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, Apache Commons StringUtils will do it for you. So will this method, though:

```
    public static String replaceChars(final String str, final String sourceChars, final String replaceChars) {

    int ix;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sb.length() ; i++) {
        if ((ix = sourceChars.indexOf(sb.charAt(i))) != -1) {
            sb.replace(i, i + 1, replaceChars.substring(ix, ix + 1));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it using standard java. There is however the [apache commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) method [StringUtils.replaceChars(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChars)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceChars%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Use in like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

StringUtils.replaceChars("ATGCATGC", "GTCA", "CAGT"); // "TACGTACG"
```

Good luck with your genetics research :)

Comment: cool, how can i import the apache commons-lang library? import apache.lang.*?

Comment: Just import the individual `StringUtils` class.

Comment: can i import this library like this from my local terminal>

Comment: Download the apache-commons library and put it in your classpath for the command, like this: `java -cp yourproject.jar;commons-lang.jar com.yourcompany.YourClass`

Answer (score 0):

You start with

```
perldoc -f tr
```

which says:

```
The transliteration operator...
```

Now that you know a good search term, enter:

```
java transliteration
```

into the little box at google.com.

This first hit looks interesting:

```
jtr, a transliteration library for Java
jtr.sourceforge.net
jtr is a small Java library that emulates the 
Perl 5 "transliterate" operation on a given string. 
Most Perl 5 features are supported, including all the standard ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to do this in Java. A really basic function to just replace every occurence of one char with another would be:

```
public static String transliterate(String str, String source, String target) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        int j = -1;
        for(int k = 0; k < source.length(); k++) {
            if(source.charAt(k) == ch) {
                j = k;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j > -1 && j < target.length()) {
            builder.append(target.charAt(j));
        } else {
            builder.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(transliterate("ABCDDCBDA", "ABCD", "1234"));
}
```